# Flexdashboard pandoc error

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

Apologies for the long and complicated code-block.

I've updated Rstudio and Shiny to the latest versions, and have unfortunately broken my nice interactive dashboard and haven't had any luck in debugging it.

Code:

---

````
title: "Antibiotic Use"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    navbar:
    source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
##Load R Libraries for Dashboard
## Dashboard
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)

## Data import and manipulation
library(tidyverse)
library(rmarkdown)

## Define function to import data from xlsx into DFs, named by xlsx tab
## Also an option to import into items on a list; but can't work out how to dplyr list data properly

importDataFrames <- function(filename){
     sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
     for(x in seq_along(sheets)){
          assign(sheets[x], readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = sheets[x], col_names = TRUE), envir = .GlobalEnv)
     }
}


## Define list vectors for sorting
hoslist <- c("hospital1", "hospital2", "hospital3", "hospital4", "hospital5")
abxlist = c("dicloxacillin", "flucloxacillin", "benzylpenicillin", "phenoxymethylpenicillin", "amoxycillin", "ampicillin", "ertapenem", "imipenem", "meropenem", "amoxycillin-clavulanate", "piperacillin-tazobactam", "ticarcillin-clavulanate", "cotrimoxazole", "cephalexin", "cefalotin", "cefazolin", "cefoxitin", "cefuroxime", "ciprofloxacin", "moxifloxacin", "norfloxacin", "cefipime", "teicoplanin", "vancomycin", "metronidazole", "tinidazole", "clindamycin", "lincomycin", "azithromycin", "erythromycin", "clarithromycin", "roxithromycin", "aztreonam",  "gentamicin", "tobramycin", "daptomycin", "linezolid", "colisitin", "fusidin", "pristinamycin", "doxycycline", "cefotaxime", "ceftazidime", "ceftriaxone", "trimethoprim")
staphpen <- c("dicloxacillin", "flucloxacillin")
narrowpen <- c("benzylpenicillin", "phenoxymethylpenicillin", "amoxycillin", "ampicillin")
penem <- c("ertapenem", "imipenem", "meropenem")
pseudpen <- c("piperacillin-tazobactam", "ticarcillin-clavulanate")
earlyceph <- c("cephalexin", "cefalotin", "cefazolin", "cefoxitin", "cefuroxime")
quinolone <- c("ciprofloxacin", "norfloxacin", "moxifloxacin")
lateceph <- c("ceftriaxone", "cefotaxime", "ceftazidime", "cefipime")
gpeptide <- c("teicoplanin", "vancomycin")
lincos <- c("clindamycin", "lincomycin")
macrolide <- c("azithromycin", "erythromycin", "clarithromycin", "roxithromycin")
aglycos <- c("gentamicin", "tobramycin", "amikacin")
other <- c("amoxycillin-clavulanate", "metronidazole", "tinidazole", "cotrimoxazole", "aztreonam", "daptomycin", "linezolid", "colisitin", "fusidin", "pristinamycin", "doxycycline", "trimethoprim")
```

```{r}
## Import data from xlsx
## Data source is 5-tabbed spreadsheet, tab hospitals, date rows, antibiotic columns, usage data
importDataFrames("district_abx.xlsx")
## Data output is 5x data frames, one for each tab

## Tidy data;  would love to do this with a list and lapply if possible
c1 <- hospital1 %>%
     gather(antibiotic, usage, -date)             # column "antibiotic" from df column headers
cact <- filter(c1, antibiotic == "activity")      # spreadsheet also includes activity data - separate this
cact <- mutate(cact, hospital = "hospital1")         # column with hospital name for activity df
c2 <- c1 %>%
     filter(antibiotic %in% abxlist) %>%          # filter out the extra columns (activity, totals)
     droplevels()
hospital1 <- mutate(c2, hospital = "hospital1")         # column "hospital" for antibiotic data

a1 <- hospital2 %>%
     gather(antibiotic, usage, -date)
aact <- filter(a1, antibiotic == "activity")
aact <- mutate(aact, hospital ="atherton")
a2 <- a1 %>%
     filter(antibiotic %in% abxlist) %>%
     droplevels()
hospital2 <- mutate(a2, hospital = "hospital2")

i1 <- hospital3 %>%
     gather(antibiotic, usage, -date)
iact <- filter(i1, antibiotic == "activity")
iact <- mutate(iact, hospital = "hospital3")
i2 <- i1 %>%
     filter(antibiotic %in% abxlist) %>%
     droplevels()
hospital3 <- mutate(i2, hospital = "hospital3")

ma1 <- hospital4 %>%
     gather(antibiotic, usage, -date)
maact <- filter(ma1, antibiotic == "activity")
maact <- mutate(maact, hospital = "hospital4")
ma2 <- ma1 %>%
     filter(antibiotic %in% abxlist) %>%
     droplevels()
hospital4 <- mutate(ma2, hospital = "hospital4")

mo1 <- hospital5 %>%
     gather(antibiotic, usage, -date)
moact <- filter(mo1, antibiotic == "activity")
moact <- mutate(moact, hospital = "hospital5")
mo2 <- mo1 %>%
     filter(antibiotic %in% abxlist) %>%
     droplevels()
hospital5 <- mutate(mo2, hospital = "hospital5")

activity <- rbind(cact, aact, iact, maact, moact)     # single df for all the activity data  
activity$date <- as.Date(activity$date)               # make sure activity dates are as.Date

usage <- rbind(hospital1, hospital2, hospital3, hospital4, hospital5) #single df for the usage data
usage$date <- as.Date(usage$date)                     # make sure usage dates are as.Date
usage$hospital <- ordered(usage$hospital, levels = c("hospital1", "hospital2", "hospital3", "hospital4", "hospital5"))                                           # bar graphs in sensible hospital order

## add column to data for antibiotic class for sorting / graphing
## there *must* be a way to apply this, surely?
usage$class[usage$antibiotic %in% staphpen == TRUE] <- "anti.staph.penicillin"
usage$class[usage$antibiotic %in% narrowpen == TRUE] <- "narrow.penicillin"
usage$class[usage$antibiotic %in% penem == TRUE] <- "carbapenem"
usage$class[usage$antibiotic %in% pseudpen == TRUE] <- "anti.pseud.penicillin"
usage$class[usage$antibiotic %in% earlyceph == TRUE] <- "early.gen.cephalosporin"
usage$class[usage$antibiotic %in% quinolone == TRUE] <- "fluoroquinolone"
usage$class[usage$antibiotic %in% lateceph == TRUE] <- "late.gen.cephalosporin"
usage$class[usage$antibiotic %in% gpeptide == TRUE] <- "glycopeptide"
usage$class[usage$antibiotic %in% lincos == TRUE] <- "lincosamide"
usage$class[usage$antibiotic %in% macrolide == TRUE] <- "macrolide"
usage$class[usage$antibiotic %in% aglycos == TRUE] <- "aminoglycoside"
usage$class[usage$antibiotic %in% other == TRUE] <- "other.antimicrobials"


```

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```{r}

## Hospital / District

selectInput("hosp",
            label = h4("Select hospital:"),
            choices = list("District" = "district",
                           "Hosp 1" = "hospital1",
                           "Hosp 2" = "hospital2",
                           "Hosp 3" = "hospital3",
                           "Hosp 4" = "hospital4",
                           "Hosp 5" = "hospital5"), selected = "hospital1")

selectInput("ctype",
            label = h4("Select Second Chart Type:"),
            choices = list("None" = "none",
                           "By class" = "byclass",
                           "By agent" = "bydrug"), selected = "byclass")
```

```{r}
conditionalPanel("input.ctype == 'byclass'",
             selectInput("abclass",
                         label = h4("Select Class:"),
                         choices = list("Anti-Pseud Penicillins" = "anti.pseud.penicillin",
                                        "Late-gen Cephalosporins" = "late.gen.cephalosporin",
                                        "Fluoroquinolones" = "fluoroquinolone",
                                        "Carbapenems" = "carbapenem",
                                        "Lincosamides" = "lincosamide",
                                        "Macrolides" = "macrolide",
                                        "Glycopeptides" = "glycopeptide",
                                        "Early Cephalosporin" = "early.gen.cephalosporin",
                                        "Narrow Penicillins" = "narrow.penicillin",
                                        "Anti-Staph Penicillins" = "anti.staph.penicillin",
                                        "Aminoglycosides" = "aminoglycoside",
                                        "Other Antibiotics" = "other.antimicrobials"), selected = "anti.pseud.penicillin")
)
```

```{r}
conditionalPanel("input.ctype == 'bydrug'",
                 selectInput("abagent",
                             label = h4("Select Agent:"),
                             choices = list("Pip-Tazo" = "piperacillin-tazobactam",
                                            "Ceftriaxone" = "ceftriaxone",
                                            "Meropenem" = "meropenem",
                                            "Ciprofloxacin" = "ciprofloxacin",
                                            "Lincomycin" = "lincomycin",
                                            "Clindamycin" = "clindamycin",
                                            "Azithromycin" = "azithromycin",
                                            "Amoxycillin" = "amoxycillin",
                                            "Co-amoxyclav" = "amoxycillin-clavulanate",
                                            "Cephazolin" = "cefazolin",
                                            "Gentamicin" = "gentamicin",
                                            "Doxycycline" = "doxycycline"), selected = "piperacillin-tazobactam")
)

```

```{r}
sliderInput("dates",
            label = h4("Select dates:"),
            min = as.Date("2006-01-01"), max = as.Date("2017-09-01"),
            value = c(as.Date("2006-01-01"), as.Date("2017-09-01")),
            timeFormat = "%b-%Y")

checkboxInput('points', 'Points', value = FALSE)
checkboxInput('smooth', 'Smooth', value = TRUE)
checkboxInput('line', "Line", value = FALSE)
checkboxInput("contct", "Control Limit", value = FALSE)

```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Most Recent data
```{r}
# infobox showing the most recent data point to see completeness of dataset
nicedate <- format(max(usage$date), "%b %Y")
valueBox(max(nicedate), icon = "fa-calendar")
```

### Number of Observations
```{r}
# infobox with number of observations; mainly to pad out the box row; probably not useful
valueBox(count(usage), icon = "fa-calculator")
```

### Mean Service Activity
```{r}
## If district selected, return mean total service activity, else facility mean activity
renderValueBox({
     if(input$hosp == "chhhs"){
          msact <- mean(summarise(group_by(activity, date), total = sum(usage))$total)
     } else {msact <- mean(summarise(group_by(filter(activity, hospital == input$hosp), date), total  = sum(usage))$total)}

     valueBox(
          value = round(msact, digits = 0),
          icon = "fa-hospital-o"
          )
})

```

### Last Month Service Activity
```{r}
## HHS or Facility service activity for most recent month in dataset
## If activity is < 15% above mean; normal
## If activity 15<30% above mean; warn
## If activity >30%; danger

renderValueBox({
      if(input$hosp == "chhhs"){
           msact <- mean(summarise(group_by(activity, date), total  = sum(usage))$total)
           actwk <- summarise(group_by(activity, date), total  = sum(usage))  # makes it easier to select!
           scact <- actwk$total[actwk$date == max(actwk$date)]
      } else {
           msact <- mean(summarise(group_by(filter(activity, hospital == input$hosp), date), total  = sum(usage))$total)
           actwk <- summarise(group_by(filter(activity, hospital == input$hosp),date), total  = sum(usage))
           scact <- actwk$total[actwk$date == max(actwk$date)]
           }

cactr <- scact / msact

if(cactr < 1.15){
     valueBox(scact,
              icon = "fa-ambulance",
              color = "primary")
} else if(cactr > 1.30){
     valueBox(scact,
              icon = "fa-warning",
              color = "danger")
} else {
     valueBox(scact,
              icon = "fa-ambulance",
              color = "warning")
}
})
```


Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Total Usage

```{r}
     renderPlot({

          if(input$hosp == "district"){

          plotdat <- summarise(group_by(filter(usage, date >= input$dates[1] & date <= input$dates[2]), date, hospital), total = round(sum(usage)))

          p <- ggplot(data = plotdat, aes(x = date, y = total)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = hospital)) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%b-%Y", name = "Month - Year") + scale_y_continuous(name = "DDD / 1000 patient-days") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral")

          print(p)
     }
           else if(input$hosp != "district"){

          plotdat <- summarise(group_by(filter(usage, hospital == input$hosp, date >= input$dates[1] & date <= input$dates[2]), date), total = round(sum(usage)))

          if(input$contct){

                    plotdat <- mutate(plotdat, contlim =(total + (sd(plotdat$total)*2)))
               }

          p <- ggplot(data = plotdat, aes(x = date, y = total)) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%b-%Y", name = "Month - Year") + scale_y_continuous(name = "DDD / 1000 patient-days")

          if(input$points){
               p <- p + geom_point()
          }
          if(input$smooth){
               p <- p + stat_smooth(colour = 'red')
          }
          if(input$line){
               p <- p + geom_line()
          }

          if(input$contct){
                    p <- p + geom_smooth(se = FALSE, aes(y = contlim), color = 'orange')
               }
          print(p)
     }
})
```

```{r}

```

Row {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Agent / Class


```{r}

renderPlot({

if(input$hosp == "chhhs"){

          plotdat <- summarise(group_by(filter(usage, date >= input$dates[1] & date <= input$dates[2]), date), total = round(sum(usage)))

          if(input$contct){

                    plotdat <- mutate(plotdat, contlim =(total + (sd(plotdat$total)*2)))
               }

          p <- ggplot(data = plotdat, aes(x = date, y = total)) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%b-%Y", name = "Month - Year") + scale_y_continuous(name = "DDD / 1000 patient-days")

          if(input$points){
               p <- p + geom_point()
          }
          if(input$smooth){
               p <- p + stat_smooth(colour = 'red')
          }
          if(input$line){
               p <- p + geom_line()
          }

          if(input$contct){
                    p <- p + geom_smooth(se = FALSE, aes(y = contlim), color = 'orange')
               }
          print(p)
     }     

        else if(input$ctype == "bydrug"){

          plotdat <- summarise(group_by(filter(usage, hospital == input$hosp, antibiotic == input$abagent, date >= input$dates[1] & date <= input$dates[2]), date), total = round(sum(usage)))
     }

     else if(input$ctype == "byclass"){
          plotdat <- summarise(group_by(filter(usage, hospital == input$hosp, class == input$abclass, date >= input$dates[1] & date <= input$dates[2]), date), total = round(sum(usage)))
     }

     if(input$contct){

                    plotdat <- mutate(plotdat, contlim =(total + (sd(plotdat$total)*2)))
               }    

     p <- ggplot(data = plotdat, aes(x = date, y = total)) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%b-%Y", name = "Month - Year") + scale_y_continuous(name = "DDD / 1000 patient-days")

          if(input$points){
               p <- p + geom_point()
          }

          if(input$smooth){
               p <- p + stat_smooth(colour = 'red')
          }

          if(input$line){
               p <- p + geom_line()
          }

          if(input$contct){
                    p <- p + geom_smooth(se = FALSE, aes(y = contlim), color = 'orange')
               }
          print(p)
})
```

### Activity
```{r}
renderPlot({

     if(input$hosp == "chhhs"){

          plotdat = summarise(group_by(filter(activity, date >= input$dates[1] & date <= input$dates[2]), date), total = sum(usage))

     } else {

          plotdat = summarise(group_by(filter(activity, hospital == input$hosp, date >= input$dates[1] & date <= input$dates[2]), date), total = sum(usage))
     }

     p <- ggplot(data = plotdat, aes (x = date, y = total)) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%b-%Y", name = "Month - Year") + scale_y_continuous(name = "Patient-days / month")

          if(input$points){
               p <- p + geom_point()
          }

          if(input$smooth){
               p <- p + stat_smooth(colour = 'blue')
          }

          if(input$line){
               p <- p + geom_line()
          }

          print(p)
})
```

### Facility Data

```{r}
DT::renderDataTable({
  tab1 <- summarise(group_by(filter(usage, hospital == input$hosp, date >= as.Date(input$dates[1]) & date <= as.Date(input$dates[2])), date), total = round(sum(usage)))
  DT::datatable(tab1, options = list(pageLength = 100))
})
```


### Agent Data

```{r}
DT::renderDataTable({
  tab2 <- summarise(group_by(filter(usage, antibiotic == input$abagent, hospital == input$hosp, date >= as.Date(input$dates[1]) & date <= as.Date(input$dates[2])), date), total = round(sum(usage)))
  DT::datatable(tab2, options = list(pageLength = 100))
})
```

### District Data

```{r}
DT::renderDataTable({
  tab3 <- summarise(group_by(filter(usage, date >= as.Date(input$dates[1]) & date <= as.Date(input$dates[2])), date), total = round(sum(usage)))
  DT::datatable(tab3, options = list(pageLength = 100))
})
```
````

Which says:
"An error has occurred. Check your logs".

Log:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:41233



processing file: index.Rmd
── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.2.1 ──
✔ ggplot2 2.2.1.9000     ✔ purrr   0.2.4     
✔ tibble  1.4.2          ✔ dplyr   0.7.4     
✔ tidyr   0.8.0          ✔ stringr 1.2.0     
✔ readr   1.1.1          ✔ forcats 0.2.0     
── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

Attaching package: 'plotly'

The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':

    last_plot

The following object is masked from 'package:stats':

    filter

The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':

    layout

Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'class'.
output file: /tmp/RtmpdrRzNh/index.knit.md

pandoc: /tmp/RtmpdrRzNh/rmarkdown-str510e40ebd6c3.html: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Warning: Error in : pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Stack trace (innermost first):
    100: pandoc_convert
     99: convert
     98: <Anonymous>
     97: do.call
     96: contextFunc
     95: .getReactiveEnvironment()$runWith
     94: shiny::maskReactiveContext
     93: <reactive>
     82: doc
     81: shiny::renderUI
     80: func
     79: origRenderFunc
     78: output$__reactivedoc__
      3: <Anonymous>
      2: do.call
      1: rmarkdown::run



processing file: index.Rmd
Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'class'.
output file: /tmp/RtmpdrRzNh/index.knit.md

pandoc: /tmp/RtmpdrRzNh/rmarkdown-str510e3380b7e9.html: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Warning: Error in : pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Stack trace (innermost first):
    100: pandoc_convert
     99: convert
     98: <Anonymous>
     97: do.call
     96: contextFunc
     95: .getReactiveEnvironment()$runWith
     94: shiny::maskReactiveContext
     93: <reactive>
     82: doc
     81: shiny::renderUI
     80: func
     79: origRenderFunc
     78: output$__reactivedoc__
      3: <Anonymous>
      2: do.call
      1: rmarkdown::run
```

This is running on an Ubuntu Linux box, with RStudio 1.1.419 and R 3.4.3, everything updated.

I'd particularly like to get the error sorted out, as I use the dash for work.  But more generally, if there are other improvements to the code, I'd appreciate that as well!

Comment: Did you update `flexdashboard`? Can you try installing the development version and try? It's a bug it seems https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/170

Comment: Success! Cheers.